# Auditing strategy for ASP.NET Identity 2.0?

Tags: asp.net-identity

It's early days of investigating whether ASP.NET Identity 2.0 would be suitable for our projects, but I haven't yet seen in ASP.NET Identity 2.0 any stubs for implement auditing of session login attempts & time of the beginning of sessions to a SessionLog table.

What are some ways this basic auditing capability could be added?

Thank you for your time,
Sky